# Stackdriver log entries with same trace ID not associated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, winston, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a NodeJS project hosted on GKE with [trace agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/trace-agent) and Stackdriver logging enabled. The project is logging to `stdout` using `winston` like this:

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, json } = format;

const addTraceId = format(info => {
  const agent = global._google_trace_agent;
  if (agent) {
    const traceProjectId = agent.getWriterProjectId();
    const traceId = agent.getCurrentContextId();
    if (traceProjectId && traceId) {
      info['logging.googleapis.com/trace'] = `projects/${traceProjectId}/traces/${traceId}`;
    }
  }
});

createLogger({
  level: 'debug',
  transports: new transports.Console()
  format: combine(
    addTraceId(),
    json()
  );
});
```

I can see traceId appear in Stackdriver and consistent across the logs within same trace. But they are all individual log entries instead of collapsed under the first entry.

I checked the request log has header `x-cloud-trace-context: "a54d7110fc59c879b7ae67fb481fb89b/113593995793831;o=1"` as well.

[image]

Also, I'm able to see in the tracing done properly trace list console.
And when I deploy the same to GAE I can see logs associated and collapsed under the first entry. Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging-winston/issues/287), there seems to already be a report of the same behaviour you are getting along with a solution in that thread

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use `@google-cloud/logging-winston`. Not really worth it for just adding traceId and http request formatting (unless I missed something.) Did it manually instead. The problem for me is that `traceId`s were attached but Stackdriver UI didn't fold them.

Comment: The two entries that you shared have different severity and that may have something to do with the reason that they are not being grouped together. I understand that this does not happen in App Engine, could you share an entry of the logs from there?

Answer (score 0):

Use `logName` `app` instead of `stdout`